# Who is eligible for a 10 year UK visa?

Tags: visas, uk, multiple-entry

I'm a retiree from United Nations after 20 years of service. During my service, I had visited UK many times officially with UN passport and privately with UK visa. I had a 5 years visa which expired in 2017. I have two daughters who are currently  working in UK and both of them are EU citizens.  My last visit to UK was in 2015.

Currently  I settled in India and I would like to visit my daughters almost every year for few days. As I had a 5 years visa before, am I eligible to get a 10 year visa?

Comment: You look like the you belong to the best possible candiate category. Go for it. Good luck.

Comment: You’re almost the epitome of the applicant to whom a 10 year validity UK visa is issued. I would put your probability at 97% with the 3% attributed to the sometimes asinine decisions of UK entry clearance officers. I went from two 5 year validity visas in succession to a refusal of a 6 months validity visa. Moral of my story is don’t cut corners, put in a well crafted application covering all the bases with no wiggle room for them to pull any nonsensical move on you. The main negative I see is you haven’t been to UK in almost four years.

Comment: @ThEiLlEgAlaLiEn Please don't just make up numbers. It's not helpful to anybody.

Comment: Edited the question to make it more broad.

Answer (score 2):

You are *eligible* to receive such a visa, but what you actually *receive* will depend upon your personal circumstances, connections to India, your finances, expressed plans for the visa's use, and credibility. None of these factors is sufficiently described in your question.

Applying for a UK visa may seem simple and straightforward, but there are a number of unexpected and surprising pitfalls. For example, two EU citizen daughters living in the UK will immediately suggest to UK immigration that your connection to the UK is stronger than your connection to India, and that you intend to stay with your family in the UK rather than returning to India when your visit is complete.

You may well be able to secure a visa, but your application will need to be carefully prepared to avoid these issues.

It'd be helpful for you to spend a few hours here on SE:Travel reading about visas to the UK and visiting family before you take any further steps.

Comment: They're EU citizens, not UK, but that probably doesn't change the conclusion in this answer. The travel history and personal circumstances seem to be very much in favor of a ten year visa, but as you note the family in the UK might work against the application.

Comment: Thanks @phoog, I didn't read the OP accurately. Now amended.